# SQL Procedure Linked to Oracle Database DateTime Conversion Issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, datetime, linked-server

I am writing a stored procedure, that fires every night at midnight, that goes out to an oracle server and grabs data and brings it to a SQL table.

Once I have the initial data in there, I alter the procedure to look at the most recent datetime... and only bring me the new data... This is causing me all kinds of issues...

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @MaxDate varchar(50)
DECLARE @Query as varchar(2000)
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @TSQL nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)

SET @MaxDate =  (SELECT MAX(Created) FROM dex_seq..OriginalSolidatReorderReportTEST)
SET @LinkedServer = 'oraclgr'

SET @TSQL = ('SELECT DISTINCT o_no, oe_state, o_prodsequenceno, o_tcreation, s1.s_no, s1.s_descr, s2.s_No CustPart,
(SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''Liability'''') liability, 
(SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''') ticket,
ct_no 
FROM J_CONTAINER
JOIN J_CONTAINERENTRY ON CT_ID = CTE_CONTAINER_ID
JOIN J_CONTAINERSUBJECT ON CTE_ID = CTES_CONTAINERENTRY_ID
JOIN J_PRODJOBENTRY ON CTE_ID = PJE_CONTAINERENTRY_ID
JOIN J_PRODJOB ON PJE_PRODJOB_ID = PJ_ID
JOIN J_SUBJECT s1 ON CTES_SUBJECT_ID = s1.S_ID
JOIN J_ORDERENTRY ON PJE_ORDERENTRY_ID = OE_ID
JOIN J_ORDER ON OE_ORDER_ID = O_ID 
JOIN J_SUBJECT s2 ON J_ORDERENTRY.OE_OTHERSUBJECT_ID = s2.s_id
WHERE o_id = oe_order_id 
AND oe_subject_id = s1.s_id 
AND o_version != ''''Initial''''
AND ct_no like ''''%LGR%''''
AND oe_scheduledtime > ( To_date(''''' + CAST(@MaxDate as varchar(200))  + ''''', ''''YYYY/MM/DD HH:Mi:SS'''') ) 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%Kyle%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%Reorder%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%Test%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%test%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%Training%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%training%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%kyle%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%Populate%'''' 
AND ((SELECT oi_stringvalue FROM j_orderinfo WHERE oi_order_id = o_id AND oi_type = ''''Comment'''' AND oi_key1 = ''''ScrapTicket'''')) NOT LIKE ''''%TEST%'''' '')')

SET @OPENQUERY = 'INSERT INTO dex_seq..OriginalSolidatReorderReportTEST SELECT o_prodsequenceno as ''CSN'', s_no as ''PartNum'', s_descr as ''PartDesc'', ticket as ''TicketNum'', o_tcreation as ''Created'', liability as ''Liability'', ''No'' as ''Submitted'', ''No'' as ''Invoiced'', ct_no as ''RackNum'',  ''No'' as ''Comments'' ,  ''No'' as ''QualityTimeComplete'',  ''No'' as ''FinanceTimeComplete'',  CustPart as ''CustPart'' FROM OPENQUERY ('+ @LinkedServer + ','''

EXEC (@OPENQUERY+@TSQL)
```

Running this is SQL gives me the error:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "oraclgr" returned message "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string".
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "oraclgr" returned message "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string".
```

The line in question is:

```
AND oe_scheduledtime > ( To_date('2016-11-07 09:23:32.0000000', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:Mi:SS') )
```

Anybody have any idea how I can reformat this line in order to read it  correctly in oracle so that I can get only the newest data??

```
AND oe_scheduledtime > ( To_date(''''' + CAST(@MaxDate as varchar(200))  + ''''', ''''YYYY/MM/DD HH:Mi:SS'''') )
```

This might be overkill, but when I run this chunk of code:

```
DECLARE @MaxDate varchar(50)
DECLARE @Query as varchar(2000)
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @TSQL nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)

SET @MaxDate =  (SELECT MAX(Created) FROM dex_seq..OriginalSolidatReorderReportTEST)
SET @LinkedServer = 'oraclgr'
SELECT @MaxDate
```

My return value is: 2016-11-07 09:23:32.0000000

Comment: Why do you tag mysql, sql-server and oracle? Do you use all of them?

Comment: `CAST(@MaxDate as varchar(200))` is ill-advised since it specifies no format. Use [`CONVERT(CHAR(19), @MaxDate, 120)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928); the corresponding Oracle format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`. Better yet might be to pass a proper parameter, but that's a bit more involved.

Comment: you could try `to_timestamp('2016-11-07 09:23:32.0000000', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff7')`. Note how I used `hh24` to indicate 24 hour time for the hours; if you miss that off and also neglect to add in the AM/PM indicator, you are potentially going to end up with problems. That applies whether you are using `to_date` or `to_timestamp`

Comment: Rather than `to_date`, you could also construct a literal with `TIMESTAMP '...'`. T-SQL's "120" format can be fed directly into this and it's potentially more efficient than a parsed date (but my Oracle experience is very limited and for all I know `to_date` is optimized perfectly).

Comment: @Boneist you are the man! This worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for the example of bad use... Makes good sense! :D

Comment: @KyleVbcrlfRickaby gosh, news to me! Last time I checked, I lacked the necessary appendages for that to be true! *{;-)